# Summing up the numbers based on a particular column value in a list

Tags: list, calculated-column

I have a list which displays the leave history of the users in a department.

Now, I want to consolidate the data in this list in such a way that I want to calculate the total number of leaves availed by each user.

For example, a user has availed leaves(any number of days) on 5 different occasions, I want to add the total no. of leave days for these 5 occasions and display as one item against the user name.

Users name is "people and groups" column type and the leave is a "calculated column" type

I couldnt find a way to display this data.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciatted.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do this is to create a custom view on your list, group by the user column and in Totals set the Leave to Sum.  When you then expand for each user you also see a total number for all the items.

You could also do this with custom XSL though that would be more complex.  The risk matrix post on [my blog](http://paylord.wordpress.com) uses the same concept you would need to consider.